# Пересчитывать значения в таблице после sortable update (jQuery UI)

Tags: javascript, jquery

[image: пример таблицы]

Доброго времени суток. Задача: каждый раз после перетаскивания строк таблицы(sortable update) и при её формировании(ajax) просчитывать время.
Т.е. (идем сверху вниз): Время окончания в 1й строке должно быть равно Время начала 2й, Время окончания 2й - Времени начала 2й и т.д.

Answer (score 0):

Решил) Сравниваю в цикле Время окончания предыдущей строки и Время начала текущей. Тут же вычисляю Время окончания текущей строки и так далее. Начинаю проверку со второй строки, т.к. первая проверяется на соответствие началу рабочего дня

```js
for (var i = 2; i <= numRows; i++) {
              var startPeriodTimeThisRow = $('#sortable tr:nth-child('+i+') td:nth-child(2)').text()
                .replace(/(([0-9])|([0,1][0-9])|(2[0-3])).([0-5][0-9])/, '$1:$5');

              var endPeriodTimePrevRow = $('#sortable tr:nth-child('+(i-1)+') td:nth-child(3)').text()
                .replace(/(([0-9])|([0,1][0-9])|(2[0-3])).([0-5][0-9])/, '$1:$5');

              if(startPeriodTimeThisRow !== endPeriodTimePrevRow) {
                $('#sortable tr:nth-child('+i+') td:nth-child(2)').text(endPeriodTimePrevRow);
              }

              var endPeriodTimeThisRow = secondsToHM(timeToSecond($('#sortable tr:nth-child('+i+') td:nth-child(2)').text()) + 
                ($('#sortable tr:nth-child('+i+')').attr('time') * 60));

              $('#sortable tr:nth-child('+i+') td:nth-child(3)').text(endPeriodTimeThisRow);
           
          }
```